# Slow Internet Connection using Wifi On ubuntu Mate 15.10

Tags: networking, drivers, 15.10, mate, ubuntu-mate

I have installed ubuntu mate 15.10 with Windows 10 but wifi works very slow.
I have following router:

```
07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:3290]
    DeviceName: Ralink WLAN Ralink RT3290LE Roma 802.11bgn 1x1 Wi-Fi + BT4.0 co
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Ralink RT3290LE 802.11bgn 1x1 Wi-Fi and Bluetooth 4.0 Combo Adapter [103c:18ec]
```

Comment: Have you tried switching to a less congested frequency on your router? Many times, switching to a less congested frequency will solve this issue. Unfortunately, the windows drivers usually have better interference mitigation applied and so it is more important to remain on a less used channel when using Ubuntu. Also, there are sometimes issues with bluetooth coexistence. There may be some way to enable or disable this modprobe option (bluetooth coexistance) if one exists.

Comment: I don't know how to do it. I am new user of ubuntu don't have any idea about it

Comment: First, press CTRL + ALT + T to open a terminal and then run the following command to list local frequencies: `nmcli dev wifi list` Then, go to your wireless router settings and switch to a channel that is not used by your neighbors.

Comment: Where is wireless router settings? and how to switch it ?? please help

Comment: It depends, with some manufacturers like cisco and linksys, you access the settings by going to http://192.168.1.1 however, sometimes it's http://10.0.0.1 You will need a password to access the settings.

Comment: i uses university wifi internet so i think it's restricted. Sir any other idea??

Answer (score 0):

If the wifi network is slow in ubuntu but in Windows everything works fine it's because of the power management of the wifi card; you can switch the power management off by adding this line

```
iwconfig wlan0 rate 54M
```

at the bottom in your /etc/rc.local; of course rc.local must be executable.

If you do this remember to disable the wifi power management in tools like laptop mode tools or tlp if you have them installed.

Comment: It gives error
"Error for wireless request "Set Bit Rate" (8B20) :
    SET failed on device wlan0 ; Operation not permitted"

Comment: oh of course you must identify your wifi card name; for example in my pc is wlan0, but in yours can be anything; find it out by typing `sudo iwconfig` in the terminal.

Comment: Still gives error
Error for wireless request "Set Bit Rate" (8B20) :
    SET failed on device wlo1 ; Operation not permitted.

Comment: did you type only `sudo iwconfig` or the whole line to add to rc.local?

Comment: I simply type "sudo iwconfig" in terminal and gives wifi card name "wlo1" after that i write " iwconfig wlo1 rate 54M" in terminal.

Comment: The above command does *not* disable wifi power save.  Mate 15.10 comes with TLP preinstalled, so the easiest way is to edit TLP's [configuration](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-configuration.html) i.e. set `WIFI_PWR_ON_BAT=1`

Comment: @ayazmuhammad the reason for the error is most likely that you need to disable wifi in network-manager, run the command, and then re-enable wifi.

Comment: @ayazmuhammad to disable powersave mode run the following command: `sudo iw dev wlo1 set power_save off` and you do not need to disable wifi to run the command here